# How to control a winforms application using another?

Tags: c#, winforms, automation, handler

I have a winforms *Application 1* which looks like this:

[image: Application 1]

This application is already built so I can't change its source code.

I want to write another winforms application, which can run hidden and auto fill that textbox in *Application 1*  then click the button.

But I don't know where to start. I Hope you can help me with some keyword, or technique that I can use in this situation. Thank you.

Comment: You are looking for [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: Or you could decompile it and modify it yourself. It's probably just a big Form1 class with all the logic inside anyway, won't be long to create a project file with that. And I highly doubt it have been obfuscated.

Comment: Personally, I'd just use a tool like AutoIt!:https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: Thank you for all of your advices. @Pierre-Luc: Actually, the Application 1 is more complicated than the form 1 above. And it have license i bought so i hope that i don't need to decompile it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good example that can solve my problem and easily to understand
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33049/WPF-UI-Automation